# Jquery Question about toggling a layer

Tags: jquery

Website http://bit.ly/euXvuJ

I'm doing the following to toggle the mouse. But when your mouse travels about half way down on the #sideshoppingcart div, the whole div goes away.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("li#menu-item-170").hover(function() {
            wwd_shopping_cart_collapser();
        },function() {
            wwd_shopping_cart_collapser();
        });
}

function wwd_shopping_cart_collapser() {
  switch($("#sideshoppingcart").css("display")) {
    case 'none':
    $("#sideshoppingcart").slideToggle("fast",function(){
            $.post( 'index.php', "ajax=true&set_slider=true&state=1", function(returned_data) { });

        });
    break;

    default:
    $("#sideshoppingcart").slideToggle("fast",function(){
            $.post( 'index.php', "ajax=true&set_slider=true&state=0", function(returned_data) { });

        });
    break;
    }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It appears like your toggle is triggered on the <li> which does not extend down. Maybe include a check to ensure the mouse is not still over the #sideshoppingcart

Answer (score 0):

I think there was just an extreme complexity with the z-indexes.

Try adding this to your css:

```
#product_showcase {
z-index:1
}
```